# Why are there unused images resources while using Google Chrome Lighthouse?

Tags: performance, performance-testing, shopware, lighthouse, core-web-vitals

I try to improve the overall performance of loading time (especially images) with the Google Chrome Lighthouse extension of this website: https://muckenthaler.de/

When the Performance Test is finished I get a list of opportunities, please see this screenshot or test for yourself: https://capture.dropbox.com/YV5ii1vrj0xpfWwK

Under **Serve images in next-gen formats** are listed some image urls (like this one: https://muckenthaler.de/media/image/54/7c/cb/Sliderbild_Produkte_Steh_SItz_Tische_2.jpg) that don't even appear on the specific page but somehow seem to get loaded into it and affect the performance.

How could I prevent this and why are these image resources loaded?

Answer (score 3):

Here are the WebPageTest results for this page: https://www.webpagetest.org/result/220529_AiDcZP_759/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1

[image]

All you need to know from this thumbnail is that yellow rows indicate HTTP redirects and purple bars represent images. The longer the bar, the longer it took for the resource to load.

So we can tell a few things from this waterfall image:

- there are many redirects
- there are many images
- many images take a very long time to load, relative to other resources

When I look up https://muckenthaler.de/media/image/54/7c/cb/Sliderbild_Produkte_Steh_SItz_Tische_2.jpg in the response headers, I see at [request 19](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/220529_AiDcZP_759/1/details/#step1_request19) that there's a redirect to that image from https://muckenthaler.de/media/image/Sliderbild_Produkte_Steh_SItz_Tische_2.jpg.

Looking up that image in your source code, I see

```html
<img src="https://muckenthaler.de/media/image/Sliderbild_Produkte_Steh_SItz_Tische_2.jpg"
  alt=""
  loading="eager">
```

Also note that this content is inside of something called `<div class="hidden-elements">`. These elements of class `emotion--element` are set to `display: none` so that the contents are not shown on screen, but `loading="eager"` on the images forces them to be loaded.

[image]

It seems like maybe your CMS (Shopware) is trying to eagerly preload images that will be used on other pages. That's not a terrible idea if you have a small number of lightweight images and users are very likely to navigate to those pages, but in this case it's loading dozens of images totalling over 30 MB. So definitely not recommended.

According to the [CWV Tech Report](https://datastudio.google.com/s/uQKDT-9jT60), Shopware websites tend to only load 2 MB of images and have pretty good Core Web Vitals performance compared to other CMS and ecommerce platforms. That leads me to believe that there might be a misconfiguration on your end, or you may have installed a bad plugin.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First things first, a big thanks to Rick  Viscomi for the research!

I found the answer which is basically Shopware 5 hidden elements, that can be shown and then be removed clicking the number next to the chain icon.

Here is a screenshot.[image]